# How to detect whether a headphone is inserted or removed in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, headphones

Is there any event in JavaScript, I can listen to in browser, through which we can know whether headphones are inserted or removed?

I assume if we are able to iterate over devices of audio output in JavaScript, is there a possibility, we can deduct the change in the number of audio output devices?

Comment: Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/destination and this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices

example:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.addEventListener('devicechange', () => {
  // Do whatever you need to with the devices
  // Maybe use enumerateDevices() to see what connected
});
```

You could check the devices already connected from the following or call it on `devicechange`:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then(devices => {
    // Check the connected devices
    console.log(devices);  
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using phone-gap plugin for the same

HTML:

```
<button class="button button-stable" ng-click="checkHeadphone()">
```

JS:

```
$scope.checkHeadphone = function () {
        window.plugins.headsetdetection.detect(function (detected) {
            alert("Headphone " + detected)
        })
    }
```